# WordPress Theme Customizer - Nested Sections?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is this possible within the Theme Customizer? I'm wondering because I have many options that I want to include in sections but obviously I don't want to overload the user with options all at once.

My assumption is no but it never hurts to ask!

Comment: You'll probably get good answers to this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/